# How can I capture a chronological record of the clients connected to a specific standalone AP?

Tags: wifi, wireless, network-access-control, time-correlation

I want to have a chronological/historical graph showing what times each client was connected to an AP using either airodump-ng with a simple script or some other free and open tool.

Comment: Cannot you get that information from the AP controller?

Comment: It doesn't give me a chronological record. Also, I want to do it from an external device to the AP and clients.